# Unit Test Order Convention?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, conventions

I am creating unit tests for an ASP.NET MVC application in C# using NUnit.

**Short Version:** Should I order my test methods alphabetically or by order of the methods belonging to the class being tested?

**For Instance:** Say I want to test the class:

```
public class MyClass{
     public void B(){}
     public void A(){}
     public void C(){}
}
```

Would it be more proper for me to structure my test class like so...

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTests{
         [Test]public void Test_B(){}
         [Test]public void Test_A(){}
         [Test]public void Test_C(){}
    }
```

or like this...

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTests{
         [Test]public void Test_A(){}
         [Test]public void Test_B(){}
         [Test]public void Test_C(){}
    }
```

A simple question I know, but I could not find any convention for this from my googling, just lots of conventions for naming test methods. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that the first one is the right way to go.....

Comment: I'd group by what they are testing first. For example everything to do about X aspect together, then by Y aspect of class etc. That's how I'd try to visually scan to find a particular test. Use `#region` `#endregion` to keep it clean.

Comment: Don't use regions, they're the bane of readable code

Comment: Ensure however that there is no dependency on the order in which the tests are run - the runner should be able to execute in any order, including all in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do them the first way.

I'd also remove Test_ from your test names, as it's redundant naming.

The best naming convention I've seen for naming tests is:

MethodName_ContextOfTest_ResultOfTest

Example:

*A_WithNullString_ThrowsException*

Makes it very easy to write your tests to test specific things, and makes it much easier for others to understand what you're testing too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the naming tip as well. I will select this as the accepted answer, for some reason I have to wait 5 minutes to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to NUnit 3 (or are already using it), you can use the `[Order]` attribute and then you won't have to mangle your test names. See the documentation for the [NUnit Order Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute).

```
public class MyFixture
{
    [Test, Order(1)]
    public void TestA() { ... }


    [Test, Order(2)]
    public void TestB() { ... }

    [Test]
    public void TestC() { ... }
}
```